# Использование шаблона MVC в небольшой игре на JavaScript + JQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, mvc

Нужно разработать небольшую игру - расширение для Хрома (вроде сапера). Ориентировочный объем кода - порядка 400 строк. Как лучше это сделать в виде одного непрерывного скрипта, или разбить весь функционал на модель, представление и контроллер и вынести их функционал в три разных скрипта. Стоит ли оно того?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Главная цель использования шаблона MVC - это обеспечение автоматического тестирования пользовательского интерфейса. Если это важно для Вашего игрового приложения, то, да, лучше даже для такого небольшого кода провести разбиение на модули (хотя их можно смело поместить в один файл). Стоит иметь в виду, что само по себе приложение для браузера уже содержит в себе многое от MVC: представление - HTML разметка, контроллер - обработчики событий JavaScript, модель - логика (в Вашем случае игровая). Пример, подхода ниже.

Разметка:

```
<body onload="View.Init();">

<input name="get" type="text" />
<input name="put" type="button" />

</body>
```

Код:

```
var View = {
    Init: function () {
        // Привязка событий
        $('#put').click(function () {
            Controller.Put(); 
        });

        // Привязка данных
        $('#get').bind('get', function () {
            $('#get').text(Model.Get());
        });
    }
}

var Controller = {
    // Стимул
    Put: function () {
        $('#get').trigger('get');
    }
}

var Model = {
    // Отклик
    Get: function () {
        return 'responce';
    }
}
```