# JavaScript MVC

Tags: javascript, mvc

Всем привет! Народ, приведите плз самый простенький пример MVC на JavaScript, чтобы понятно было что к чему. 
Спасибо=)

Comment: А зачем вообще это?

Comment: Как зачем? Во-первых для удобства...Нужно в общем... В нагуглил много статей, но все уж очень много пишут ненужного или непонятного.

Comment: мне в своё время помог [Hello Backbone.js Tutorial](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/), но всё же лишний раз подумайте стоит ли игра свеч, может быть лучше будет написать в лоб.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите здесь: [использование шаблона MVC в небольшой игре на JavaScript + JQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596#598).

P.S. Вообще обычный сайт по факту почти всегда является обобщенным MVC-приложением (M - база данных, V - разметка страницы, J - контроллер). Но если сайт целиком живет на стороне клиента (что возможно для HTML5 приложений), то можно искусственно бить JS под MVC.

Comment: Спасибо! Лови плюс =)

Answer (score 0):

Ext js посмотри, sencha.com их адрес